# In App Billing BroadcastReceiver Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, in-app-billing

I am opening a Activity with ActivityResult and after buying a item successfully, I am closing the current activity which holds purching process and send data back. But Leak Canary catch a memory leak about BillingBroadcastReceiver. I init billing client `OnCreate` and release `onDestroy`.

Here is my init method which called in `OnCreate`

```
billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(this).build();
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(int responseCode) {

                if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.
                    loadProducts();
                } else {
                    // Error
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                Timber.d("Connection Error");
            }
        });
```

Load Product infos when `billingClient` is ready

```
private void loadProducts() {

if (billingClient.isReady()) {

    List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>(getViewModel().getSkuIdList());
    SkuDetailsParams params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder().setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP).build();

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params, new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

            if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                Timber.d("SkuList --> %s", skuDetailsList.size());

            } else {
                Timber.d("Can't querySkuDetailsAsync, responseCode: %s", responseCode);
            }

        }
    });

} else {
    Timber.d("Billing Client not Ready");
}
}
```

Here is my release method which called in `OnDestroy`

```
    if (billingClient != null && billingClient.isReady()) {
        billingClient.endConnection();
        billingClient = null;
    }
```

OnPurchaseUpdated I made a service call and close this activity based on service result.

```
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) { 
        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
            billingClient.consumeAsync(purchase.getPurchaseToken(), new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsumeResponse(int responseCode, String purchaseToken) {
                    if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchaseToken != null) {
                        Timber.d("onConsumeResponse --> %s", purchaseToken);
                        getViewModel().informPurchase(necessary data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
        // Handle an error caused by a user canceling the purchase flow.
        Timber.d("Billing Cancelled");

    } else {
        Timber.d("An Error Occured");
    }
}
```

I am using latest library for in app purchase

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2.1'
```

After buying a item successfully and close recent activity, Leak Canary shows me this error. How can I avoid this memory leak?

[image: BroadcastError]

Comment: looks like `endConnection` is not removing the reference to the activity that  `setListener(this)` is setting. Have you verified that `billingClient.endConnection();` is actually being called by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: I checked by setting breakpoint, `billingClient.endConnection();` called normally. I also call `endConnection` method in observer of  `informPurchase` method for test purpose, still the same leak happens @CésarDeLaVega

Comment: Also add your broadcastmanager class

Comment: Problem is here @ShwetaChauhan, I do not have a boardcastmanager class, it is billing library's class

Comment: @ysfcyln have you found a solution?

Comment: @dtunctuncer  unfortunately not :(

Comment: @ysfcyln Hey, man. Have you found a solution for this? I'm using version 3.0.2 and the problem still persists.

Comment: Nope, They said that, issue has been fixed. It shall be rolled out with the next release. You can check out [this issue](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/185#issuecomment-756279353)

Comment: Feb 5th 2021 and the issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The Activity is being destroyed before the `billingClient` is ready so 
`billingClient.isReady` will be false and the `endConnection` will never be called, so the reference to the Activity (the Activity is the listener of the BillingClient) won't be removed and you will have a leak.

To fix, just do:

```
if (billingClient != null) {
        billingClient.endConnection();
        billingClient = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not work. `billingClient` is always ready and `billingClient.endConnection();` called properly, I double checked with debug. I also checked with removing `isReady` and result is still same